# how to get 'z' in ECDSA?

Tags: private-key, ecdsa

There are 2 nice articles about ECDSA of getting private key by the same 'r'. I dont know how to get the 'z'. Can u describe in detail and give an example?[first article](https://web.archive.org/web/20160308014317/http://www.nilsschneider.net/2013/01/28/recovering-bitcoin-private-keys.html)
[second article](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/35848/recovering-private-key-when-someone-uses-the-same-k-twice-in-ecdsa-signatures/35850#35850)